# Spring MVC Controller misunderstanding

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

Code from a controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;


    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {

        model.put("items", itemService.getItems());

        return "home";
    }
}
```

And a part of the correspondent **home.jsp**:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
   ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

In a browser I get elements that are returned from `itemService.getItems().`
How Spring finds out that `model` map contains values to be request attributes?

Comment: Its the Spring DispatcherServlet that does it. Its also the one that finds out, which controller and which method on that controller should be called.

Comment: But how the DispatcherServlet finds out that the values from the map should be copied to request attributes? I mean  **model** is a simple parameter...
Does the DispatcherServlet copy contents of all parameters of type **Map** to request attributes?

Comment: The documentation says yes ^^

Answer (score 1):

*Does the DispatcherServlet copy contents of all parameters of type Map to request attributes?*

Yes, Spring MVC copies all the parameters from model to *HttpServletRequest* object. The reason why Spring people chosen not to use the *HttpServeltRequest* directly, is due to the requirement that they want to be as independent from the view technologies as possible, so being able to drive the view technologies that don't depend on the *HttpServeltRequest*

Exposing the model as request parameters is a facet of view, and you'll find the appropriate code if you check out the source of SpringMVC's [InternalResourceView](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.html) which extends from [AbstractView](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractView.html) that holds the [exposeModelAsRequestAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractView.html#exposeModelAsRequestAttributes-java.util.Map-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) method